# In Qt ":-1: error: LNK1168: cannot open J:\Projects\bin\test-lib.dll for writing"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, qt5

I am getting this error when I try to run my project in Qt-

```
:-1: error: LNK1168: cannot open J:\Projects\bin\test-lib.dll for writing
```

I tried to restart my pc and the project run without any problem. But after the first run this error pops out. What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: You must close the program that is using that dll.  Whether you "see" the program or not, it is still running.  And MS Windows has terrible difficulty with writing to a file that is in use.

Comment: But how can I find what program is running? I can not find anything running in qt.

Comment: Ah! Never mind. I found the error bugging me. I had to go to "Application Output" and find out a very small splendidly hidden Stop button to close the running program.